# How to use perl one-liner as an alias

Tags: perl, shell, solaris, tcsh, uniq

To filter non-consecutive lines of file, the below one-liner working fine:

```
cat filename | perl -ane 'print unless $a{$_}++'
```

However, when i tried to make it as an alias and do, its not working as expected

```
alias uniqlines " cat \!* | perl -ane 'print unless \$a{\$_}++' "
```

erroring out as below

```
   a: Undefined variable.
```

Using tcsh shell for SunOS operating system

Comment: you are aware of the `uniq` command?

Comment: Uniq works for only consecutive lines only right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash this syntax works:

```
alias uniqlines="perl -ane 'print unless \$a{\$_}++' "
```

Here is a way that seems to work even in tcsh:

```
alias uniqlines 'perl -ane '"'"'print unless $a{$_}++'"'"' '
```

Comment: Removing the useless `cat {} |`.

Comment: I'm using SunOS tcsh, still its doesn't working for me, getting the same error

Comment: Read this for the problem of quotes in tcsh aliases: http://engtech.wordpress.com/2006/05/25/how-to-embed-single-quotes-in-a-tcsh-alias/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a function instead:

```
uniqlines(){ cat "$@" | perl -ane 'print unless $a{$_}++'; }
```

But this is pretty much just a fancy way of saying:

```
alias uniqlines=uniq
```

Comment: Even though it's not the solution you're asking for I suggest that you simply use "uniq". It does what you want.

Comment: Uniq command is to filter consecutive repeated lines only , it doesn't help to filter out non consecutive repeated lines, Hence i 'm going for perl here

Comment: What about "sort -u filename" ? It does a little more than your alias (sorting), but filters out non consecutive equal lines.

Comment: Correct!! but i dont want to disturb the file (lines) order